# system.threading.timer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I need to have a specific process(method) run once a day at a given time and was wondering if this can be done using the timer control.

Comment: Yes, it can.  Were you asking how?  Also, using the task scheduler may be a more appropriate way to accomplish this, unless the program is already long-running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been stated, if your process isn't already running, then use Task Scheduler to handle this for you.

However, if you have some background service or something already running, then use a timer, and have it check the system time.  Timers are not necessarily accurate, and after a day's worth of running, I would expect them to be way off.

Set up a timer with an interval of 3000ms or so, and when that interval hits, then check the system time to see if it is time for your method to run.

Comment: +1 spot on answer.  I had this problem once and originally started making a windows service, but theres simply no point in having something run - but not actually doing anything

Answer (score 1):

You should create a program that does that process, then exits.

You should then schedule the program using Windows Task Scheduler.